# Logging requests/Response from a .Net core Web api client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have made a  Web api(Web API-X) in .Net core 2 which calls a few Web Services(which includes wcf and rest APIs of third parties) and gives response to the various different applications(internal to my ogranization say app-a, app-b,app-c). So basically Web Api-X, works as bridge between all of third party apis and all the internal applications.

in Web API-X : I want to log all the calls to external APIs (preferably using middle ware component).  Please let me know how it could be achieved.
p.s - I am already logging all the requests from (app-a, app-b) etc into Web API-X using middleware, however I have no clue how I can log external API requests from Web API-x.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look on how [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) does it, see [this post](https://lowleveldesign.org/2017/01/02/how-dependency-calls-are-tracked-by-the-application-insights/) for example.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. Just to clarify things a bit, I want to log request/response from a Consumer application (which is made in .Net core 2)  ...

Comment: yes, well and logging inbound traffic is easy using middleware as you already did but outgoing calls you have to track manually or write something like application insights which listens to framework events to detect outbound requests.

Comment: If you could instead log method calls to the classes that in turn made requests to external resources, would that suffice? It would be much simpler to implement and would likely give you the information that you need.